# getting text from image using pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pyautogui to automate a process. I have a report in SAP. I have to go through each row of that report and compare the values of one of its column. Pyautogui does not support OCR and I know that I can use pytesseractt. My idea is to iterate through each row of the report. Take the screenshot of the data in a cell using pyautogui, convert it into text using pytesseractt and compare. But it is a very inefficient and time-consuming approach. Can anyone suggest a better solution.